# Scheme: populating a vector using recursion?

Tags: recursion, vector, scheme

I am new to Scheme - I am currently trying to learn the syntax and how to think recursively. I came to a section on vectors and wanted to be able to set values in my vector via some kind of looping (using recursion of course). I have this variable:

```
(define my-vector (make-vector 5))
```

which I then want to populate using the `vector-set!` procedure. Normally in C++ (the only other language I am really familiar with) this would be done in an iterative fashion, eg

```
//...

std::vector<int> myVector;

for(int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)    // populate the vector
    myVector.push_back(i);

std::vector<int>::const_iterator outIter;

for(outIter = myVector.begin();
    outIter != myVector.end(); ++outIter)
    std::cout << *outIter << " ";

std::cout << std::endl;

//...
```

However, I know that this kind of thing should be done via recursion in Scheme. What would a  recursive `populate-vector` procedure might look like??

Comment: vectors in Scheme are not the same as `vector`s in C++. vectors in Scheme have a size fixed at the time it's created, and can't be resized; kind of like arrays allocated with `new int[size]` in C++

Comment: Noted. Yes, I see that `vector` has to be defined with a fixed size, unlike `<vector>` in C++. I just wanted to know how to abstract the idea of "populate some container" in Scheme.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
(let f ((i 0))
  (when (< i 5)
    (vector-set! my-vector i i)
    (f (+ i 1))))
```

You can try it online [here](http://eval.ironscheme.net/?id=16).

You can also try using the `DO` syntax, but most find it hard to remember :)

Learning to use named `LET` is very important.

Also note, a Scheme vector is just a fixed-sized array.

Comment: OK. Thanks. Still trying to wrap my head around when to use LET over LAMBDA, etc.

Comment: Also, I am using guile for my scheme interpreter and the above doesn't seem to work. It seems to not like the "unbound variable WHEN" is this a non-standard procedure??

Comment: I used `;; (let f ((i 0)) (if (< i 5) (begin ...` which seemed to work.

Comment: You are probably using an older version of guile.

Comment: @djhaskin987: Never seen what? (I guess you speaking about the online evaluator ;p)

Comment: @leppie: the online evaluator, but also, named let's. This makes things so much easier, both the online evaluator (which I have been looking for for months) and the named let.

Answer (score 0):

One option would be something like this:

```
void PopulateVector(vector<int>& vec, int n) {
    if (n < 0) return;

    PopulateVector(vec, n - 1);

    vec.push_back(n);
}
```

The idea is as follows.  First, if you're trying to create a vector with values ranging from 0 to some negative number, we do nothing; there are no values to add.  Otherwise, we first fill in the vector with the values 0 through n - 1, then append n to the vector.

Note that this is a very inefficient procedure in terms of memory usage; it requires linear memory for the call stack.  The iterative version is likely to be far superior.  We can rewrite this function to be tail-recursive and hope that the optimizer eliminates the recursion, but there is no guarantee that this will happen (while, IIRC, tail call elimination is required by Scheme).  The idea is to use a wrapper function so that we can count up to n rather than down from n:

```
void PopulateVector(vector<int>& vec, int n) {
    if (n < 0) return;

    PopulateVectorRec(vec, 0, n);
}

void PopulateVectorRec(vector<int>& vec, int current, int n) {
    if (current > n) return;

    vec.push_back(current);

    PopulateVectorRec(vec, current + 1, n);
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Yes, I have heard that the iterative version is better for this kind of thing. But it still uses recursion correct? Except it is at the "tail" of the procedure? I should probably read up more on tail-call elimination...